# Non-differentiable Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute the expression $\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-∇f(0,0)•(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||}$, for f$(x,y)=(2x^3+3y^3)^{1/3}$.

How do you find $∇f(0,0)$?? Isn't this undefined?

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla f(0,0)(e_{1})=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\nabla f(0,0)(e_{2})=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ if they exist.

Comment: But these do not exist, right? As the denominator is $(2x^3+3y^3)^{2/3}$. So how do you compute the original expression?

Comment: The exponent is $2/3$ or $1/3$?

Comment: Well after differentiating, the denominator should be to the power of 2/3 (1/3-1)?

Comment: Either way, there is division by 0.

Comment: You have to go through by definition, $f(h,0)=2^{1/3}h$, so $(f(h,0)-f(0,0))/h=2^{1/3}$, the limit exists.

Comment: Thank you :) i can't believe i didn't think of that